# How to prevent the UI from crashing in angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an angular 4 app. The HTML page on of my component is
`<p> {{ myJson['Key'].toLowerCase() }} </p>`. But, the problem is sometimes 'Key' would not be present in some JSON files and the UI crashes with

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

I have an error handler `class myErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler` that logs all the errors. But, sometimes due to invalid json data, the key may be absent or the data might not be there. apart from using `*ngIf` to check each and every tag, is there a way i could prevent the UI from crashing? When the crash happenes, The UI elements are not aligned properly (imagine one element is kind of laid besides a replica of itself). If i want to prevent this from happening, what are the ways?

Thanks in advance. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: just sanitize your json data in your component class. don't just shove it into the view. but you could use the hasOwnProperty('Key') before trying to access it.

Comment: In you're p tag have *ngIf="myJson['key']"  Make sure the objects you are rendering exist and are defined

Comment: i have added ngIf on all the tags now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "[Elvis operator](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/elvis-operator-in-angular-2.0)" `?.` (aka the "Safe Navigation" operator):

```
<p>{{ myJson?.Key?.toLowercase() }}</p>
```

Comment: Official doc [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator)

Comment: @tatsu in typescript use the logical OR operator to perform null-coalescing.

Comment: elaborate? you can claim 100 points here if you really have a solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57960362/angular-8-native-typescript-crash-free-accessor-shorthand