# Angular 8 Native Typescript crash-free, accessor shorthand

Tags: angular, typescript, ecmascript-2017

Angular 8 :

I used to use as a short hack on typescript side :

`object['accessor']['accessor']['accessor']`

to get

`object.accessor.accessor.accessor`

without running the risk of throwing an error if one of the children was empty.

What is the best way to do this by today's ECMA Script standards inside the typescript file?

EDIT :

I found this https://medium.com/inside-rimeto/optional-chaining-in-typescript-622c3121f99b

the b/ Nested Ternary Expressions seems the best but it seems convoluted

EDIT 2 :

nevermind, this crashes the application irrecuperably (at the component level, though) just as much.

it seem newer anguar rules are more strict. they just haven't provided an alternative.

Comment: The medium post you linked lists pretty much every possible workaround for this problem. Is something in that post unclear or are you just looking for a better solution? (which doesn't exist AFAIK)

Comment: a better solution. the recent changes in angular 8 makes even those suggestions fail. The only success I got was full verbose `if(object.accessor !== null && object.accessor !== undefined ) { console.log(object.accessor.accessor.accessor) }` this is less than ideal when you have to repeat for many objects and keys that you cannot iterate over

Comment: Dupe of [Test for existence of nested JavaScript object key](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2631001/215552)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I was looking for a shorthand but that recursive function might already save me some lines. I'll return the object instead of true/false though, I need the value straight away

Comment: But `object['accessor']['accessor']['accessor']` _will_ throw error in the same situations where `object.accessor.accessor.accessor` throws.

Comment: I know. that's my point.  but it's fine @HereticMonkey linked me to a satisfactory recursive solution. it's not as condensed as I might have hoped but it's already a bit better then what we generally have to do.

Comment: Is this shorthand enough? `(() => {try{return object.accessor.accessor.accessor}catch(e){return default;}})();`  ... optional chaining can't come soon enough :)

Comment: very interesting, right now it doesn't work for me at a code-analysis level. `return default;` and the final `();` seem not to be accepted in current Typescript syntax, are you sure there are no mistakes there? If this can actually work this will constitute the answer I am looking for.

Comment: Ha, I posted. Didn't know if it would be the answer you were seeking.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the boolean expression approach.

```
let object = {
  accessor: {
    accessor: {
      accessor: "test"
    }
  }
}

if (object
   && object.accessor
   && object.accessor.accessor
   && object.accessor.accessor.accessor) {
  console.log(object.accessor.accessor.accessor);
} else {
  console.log(null);
}
```

If you don't care about compile time error checking you could do something weird like this. I wouldn't recommend it.

```
function tryGetValue(obj, propertiesPath) {
  if (!obj) {
    return null;
  }

  if (!propertiesPath) {
    return obj;
  }

  let current = obj;
  let properties = propertiesPath.split(".");
  for (let i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {
    if (current[properties[i]] !== undefined) {
      current = current[properties[i]];
    } else {
      current = null;
      break;
    }
  }

  if (current !== undefined) {
    return current;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

console.log(tryGetValue(object, "accessor.accessor.accessor"));
```

Comment: testing the object without an equal condition will result in a crash if the object is undefined. I don't know if this is an angular thing or not but : `if(object.accessor)` = crash `if(object.accessor !== undefined && object.accessor !== null)` = success. beats me why it is that way but it is that way.

Answer (score 2):

there is an npm package for this named [snq(Safe Navigation Query)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/snq) by armanozak. Very simple and robust solution.

You can use it like this

```
snq(() => object.accessor.accessor.accessor, anyDefaultValueIfYouLike);
```

And If you wonder how it is working, here is the source code I copied from [github repo](https://github.com/armanozak/snq)

```
export default function snq<T = any>(callback: () => T, defaultValue?: T) {
  try {
    const result = callback();
    return typeof result === 'undefined' ? defaultValue : result;
  } catch (err) {
    if (err instanceof TypeError) {
      return defaultValue;
    }

    throw err;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do the following

```
// Sample object

const object = {
    someKey: 'First Level Value',
    accessor: {
        someKey: 'Second Level Value',
        accessor: {
            someKey: 'Third Level Value',
            accessor: 'Accessor Value'
        }
    }
};

// Using ternary expression to do conditional validation check
// Usage --> condition to check ? 'Do this if condition is true' : 'Do this if condition is false'

const accessorValue = object ? // first (?) operator
    object.accessor ? // second (?) operator
        object.accessor.accessor ? // third (?) operator
            object.accessor.accessor ? // fourth (?) operator
                object.accessor.accessor.accessor :
                null : // to match the first (?) operator
            null : // to match the second (?) operator
        null : // to match the third (?) operator
    null; // to match the fourth (?) operator

console.log(accessorValue); // Accessor Value
```

Comment: this throws and undefined exception when an accessor is not there and the rest of the component stops loading.

Comment: It might show a compile-time TypeScript error, but there should be no run-time error.

Comment: no I'm talking about a runtime error when the object either does not exist or does not posses that child.

Comment: if the accessor does not exist, it will return undefined, which is falsey, so it should just go to the false side of the ternary.

Comment: With typescript you can/should write an interface class for your object/model to detect possible runtime error while developing.

Comment: that's not getting rid of the error that's just moving it somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

I like using [Ramda's path function](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#path) in my angular projects.

```
import * as R from 'ramda';

const leaf = R.path(['accessor', 'accessor', 'accessor'], object);
```

Another appraoch that I have been using to avoid crash if child is empty (when ramda is not around), comes from inspiration from swifts `.?` and `??` operators to default to something if child is empty.

**You don't need fancy functions, this single liner will do the trick crash proof**

```
const leaf = (((object || {}).accessor || {}).accessor || {}).accessor;
```

**In action:**

```js
const wrongObject = { accessor: null };
const validObject = { 
  accessor: {
    accessor: {
      accessor: 'your leaf value'
    }
  }
};

// crash proof, returning: undefined
const wrongLeaf = (((wrongObject || {}).accessor || {}).accessor || {}).accessor
console.log(wrongLeaf);

// or even with fallback / default value
const defaultLeaf = (((wrongObject || {}).accessor || {}).accessor || {}).accessor || 'default 123';
console.log(defaultLeaf);

const validLeaf = (((validObject || {}).accessor || {}).accessor || {}).accessor
console.log(validLeaf);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this as a shorthand, which would allow the types to flow through, I assume.

```
const value = (() => {try{return object.accessor.accessor.accessor}catch(e){return yourDefault;}})();
```

Comment: really in the nick of time. 14 mins left.